# React-Native unable to call function

Tags: reactjs, function, react-native

In my app i have  a function outside **'export'** which return a view, on click event of a button inside view another function is invoked which defined inside **'export'**.
While clicking button error is received - 
`this4.myFunc is not a function.`
screenshot attached below - [error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMrfr.png)

below is my code -

```
export default class RosterView extends Component{
   constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state={
    ....
   }

  render () {
    mContext = this;
    return (
       <List dataArray={mContext.state.rosterList}
       renderRow={(item) =>
        <View style = {MainView.PlayerSelected}>
         <AddPlayersToRosterList
          data={item}/>
      </View>
    }>
</List>
     );
    }
   isExist = (item) =>{
     //My Code
     return flag;
   }
   addRemovePlayer = (data) =>  {
    //My Code
   }


}

 const AddPlayersToRosterList= ({data}) => (
          (!mContext.isExist(data))?
          <View style = {MainView.PlayerSelected}>
             <Ripple style={MainView.PlayerAddRemoveContainer} onPress={()=> this.addRemovePlayer(data)}>             
             </Ripple>
          </View>
 )
```

when press button inside `AddPlayersToList`, `this.addRemovePlayer()` shows error.

please provide your help how to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your `render` function?

Comment: and where are your `addRemovePlayer()` and `isExist()` functions? the functional Component `AddPlayersToList` don't know where to search that functions.

Comment: @Aravinds i have updated my code please check

Comment: Where is your `Ripple` comp. Please share all relevant code

Comment: answer updated. let me know if helps

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have many errors here. i tried to rewrite your code. try this here. and let me know if that helps. delete the whole `AddPlayersToRosterList` functional component that you wrote at the end. and rewrite it inside the component RosterView as a function.

The problem is, if you try to use functions that were not declared inside functional components, those components dont know the functions you are trying to call. In the case of `const AddPlayersToRosterList` you call the functions `isExist(data)` and `this.addRemovePlayer(data)`, that were declared inside `RosterView`, but not inside `AddPlayersToRosterList`.

```
       // add this function inside RosterView 
       AddPlayersToRosterList = (data) => {
              (!this.isExist(data))?
              <View style = {MainView.PlayerSelected}>
                 <Ripple 
                  style={MainView.PlayerAddRemoveContainer}  
                  onPress={() => this.addRemovePlayer(data)}>             
                 </Ripple>
              </View>
     }

       render (){
        var mContext = this;
        return (
           <List dataArray={mContext.state.rosterList}
             renderRow={(item) =>
              <View style = {MainView.PlayerSelected}>
                {this.AddPlayersToRosterList(item)// make sure you call the function here} 
              </View>
           }>
           </List>
         );        
       }
```

you could just pass as props the functions you need to your functional component without delete anything. but it would be cost more memory and compution power that you probably need depending of how many props you want to pass.

```
const AddPlayersToRosterList= ({data, isExist, mContext, addRemovePlayer}) => (
          (!mContext.isExist(data))?
          <View style = {MainView.PlayerSelected}>
             <Ripple 
               style={MainView.PlayerAddRemoveContainer} 
               onPress={()=> this.addRemovePlayer(data)}
             >             
             </Ripple>
          </View>
 )
```

and in your render method

```
 render () {
    mContext = this;
    return (
       <List dataArray={mContext.state.rosterList}
         renderRow={(item) =>
          <View style = {MainView.PlayerSelected}>
            <AddPlayersToRosterList
              data={item} 
              isExist={this.isExist} 
              mContext={mContext}
              addRemovePlayer={this.addRemovePlayer}
            />
          </View>
       }>
       </List>
     );
  }
```